# Bash error: Division on zero error when using directory path

Tags: bash, variables, scripting

I'm writing a bash script that checks the number of files in a directory and if it's over a certain number, do something. The code is here:

```
DIR=/home/inventory
waiting="$((ls ${DIR}/waiting/ -1 | wc -l))"

echo $waiting

if [ $waiting -gt 3 ]
   then
     (DO SOME STUFF HERE)
fi
```

The error I am getting is this line....

```
waiting="$((ls ${DIR}/waiting/ -1 | wc -l))"
```

Specifically the error is ....

```
division by 0 (error token is "/home/inventory/waiting/ -1 | wc -l")
```

I thought trying to put the number of files in this directory into a variable would work using $(()).

Does anyone have an idea why this is failing? 
Many TIA.....
Jane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single parenthesis:

```
waiting="$(ls ${DIR}/waiting/ -1 | wc -l)"
```

`$(( ... ))` is used to perform arithmetic calculations.

From the man page:

> `((expression))`
>
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below  under  ARITHMETIC  EVALUATION.   If  the value  of  the  expression  is  non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

Comment: Works like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use output of `ls` to count number of files/directories in a sub -directory as file names may contain newlines or glob characters as well.

Here is one example of doing it safely using `gnu find`:

```
dir=/home/inventory
waiting=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '.' | wc -c)
```

If you don't have `gnu find` then use:

```
waiting=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec printf '.' \; | wc -c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to pipe the waiting variable through awk to check for a value greater than 3 so:

DIR=/home/inventory
waiting="$((ls ${DIR}/waiting/ -1 | wc -l))"

echo $waiting

res=$(echo $waiting | awk '{ if ( $0 > 3 ) print "OK" }')

if [ $res == "OK" ]
   then
     (DO SOME STUFF HERE)
fi

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar problem even without using the compound command    `((..))`

Be sure your variables are not defined using `let` keyword, as it would force shell arithmetic evaluation too.

From the [referece](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, as one of the
> shell expansions or by using the (( compound command, the let builtin,
> or the -i option to the declare builtin.